# Maximum of a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the maximum value of a $4 \times 4$ determinant which has two $4$s and the rest of the elements are either $1$ or $-1$.
I don't really know how to approach this. I tried writing down a couple of determinants of this form, but this is far from a solution.

Comment: Why not use brute-force enumeration?  There are not all that many cases to try.

Comment: I get $58$ for $$\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 4&1&1&-1\\ -1&4&1&1
\\ 1&-1&1&1\\ 1&1&-1&1\end {array}
 \right]
$$

Comment: Yes, that determinant is $58$ indeed. I believe there are a lot of cases, but I suppose you found a way to get rid of some of them, how did you do this?

Comment: As I said, I used brute-force enumeration.  Well, not completely brute: we may assume wlog that one of the $4$'s is in the top left.  That left $245760$ cases to try.  I could have used symmetry to reduce it further, but that's already not too bad on a fast computer.

Comment: This problem comes from a contest in my country and the official solution claims $25$ is the maximum value, which is obviously false, so their solution is definitely wrong. I wonder if this can actually be solved mathematically or is one of those fake problems.